# Docker container manual networking setup not working

Tags: networking, docker

I have an  application environment where two containers need to talk to each other.  Container A gets a message from Container B, and Container A initiates a connection back to Container B using the IP address of the connection from B.

So I need the container IP addresses to be on the same network as the hosts. 
I followed this [Docker + Bridges + DHCP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155990/docker-bridges-dhcp) instruction.

**Problem:** I never get the `eth0` device in the container.
My container is started from `ubuntu:14.04`, I added `lxc` to it.

The container is started with additional params  `--net=none --lxc-conf=\"lxc.network.type=veth\" \
--lxc-conf=\"lxc.network.link=br0\"  --lxc-conf=\"lxc.network.name=eth0\" --lxc-conf=\"lxc.network.flags=up\"  "`

But I don't see that interface in the container.. ifconfig returns only for lo.

What did I miss? 
My container has a custom startup script.

---

**Edit:** My host is runnung ubuntu 14.04 latest.
the host has `lxc` installed as well as docker (installed today).

Docker inspect on the container shows the `lxc-conf` keys defined.

It's like `lxc` is not executing, but I don't know why. Debug of `lxc` invocations is a known issue with no current solution.